# Xcode not recognizing frameworks correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, parseui

Yesterday everything was working fine. This morning I came back and I suddenly received the error "No such module 'ParseUI'." I have the ParseUI installed. I have `import Parse` and `import ParseUI` in about 10 of my swift files. But when I build I only get the error message on 1 file. So I removed the `import ParseUI` and then I got the error message "No such module Parse." I've been working with this project for a few weeks, and this is the first time I'm seeing either of these errors. Additionally, when I put `import RandomFramework` ( a framework that doesn't even exist) it doesn't recognize that as an error, rather still says ParseUI isn't valid.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: i60.tinypic.com/2604gwm.png]

I've cleaned, restarted Xcode, restarted my computer, and checked build Phases/link binaries with libraries, and everything was still there. This just seems bizarre, especially after having no such problems like this for a few weeks. It's even crazier that the `import RandomFramework` raises no errors. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Did you delete everything in the derived data folder? (I.e. locate derived data folder in "Preferences" - "Locations", quit Xcode, delete everything inside the `DerivedData` folder, and then restart Xcode)